# woocommerce checkout update has stopped working in v 2.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Before updating to woocommerce 2.5 this code would update the checkout when suburb, state or postcode were updated. After update from 2.4 to 2.5 it has stopped working.

```
// Trigger shipping cost update on postcode change and billing city change
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('form.checkout').on( 'change', '#billing_postcode_field.update_totals_on_change input.input-text, #billing_city_field.update_totals_on_change input.input-text, #shipping_postcode_field.update_totals_on_change input.input-text, #shipping_city_field.update_totals_on_change input.input-text', function(){
        dirtyInput = true;
        $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
    })
});
```

Comment: did you cleared  browser cookies? after update sometime it refresh continously